# Perl UTF8 CGI and DBI ... what's the correct workflow?

Tags: mysql, perl, utf-8

I am having the pleasure of rebuilding a perl based web framework to UTF8 support. I took the following steps

for the main script:
`use open IO => ":utf8",":std";`
`use utf8;`

for the DBI Adapter:
`$self->{dbh}->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1;'`

and in my request parser for POST and GET, based on CGI:
`foreach (@val) { $_ = decode("UTF-8",$_); }`

This, as far as I can tell, works just fine on my local Ubuntu with Perl 5.10.1, but on the webserver which runs 5.10, decoding POST or GET will mess up the text.

I must admit, I am very confused by the whole UTF8 thing.   I need to
Read Templates
Get data from mySQL
Process POST and GET 
insert into mySQL
write Templates

Is there anything I'm forgetting here? What could cause the inconstant behaviour? Does every module I use in the main script need to specifically `use utf8` or is it enough if the main script does that?

Thanks for any hints,
thomas

Comment: `use utf8;` merely tells the Perl interpreter that _your source code_ is encoded in utf8. Unless you have utf-8 string literals in your code, you have no need for that line, at all.

Comment: Have also a look at http://www.slideshare.net/Penfold/perl-and-unicode, specifically about using `Encode` to encode/decode text, and making sure the client knows to send data in the correct content-type.

Comment: Give a concrete example how "decoding POST or GET will mess up the text". Show the complete Perl code necessary to reproduce the problem, the Web form that constructs the request, and a dump of the HTTP request/response.

Comment: @mfontani: I am confused about encoding actually. In my workflow (parse an utf-8 encoded document, regex replace data from a utf8 mySQL table and output it using IO utf8), when do I have to encode anything? This seems to work just fine without using en- or decode(), the only thing is, for some reason the webserver needs to decode request data ...

Answer (score 4):

`use utf8;` is, as several people have said, a no-op as far as your i/o problems are concerned: all it says is 'treat my source code as utf8 encoded'.

MySQL/DBI approach is bang on the money.

For CGI, update to a recent CGI and set `$CGI::PARAM_UTF8=1` and it'll do the `decode()` for you. (As a general tip, BTW, `decode_utf8()` is considerably faster!)

As for the other problem, you may want to compare your Apache server configs to see if [AddDefaultCharset](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset) is set to some non-helpful value.

Also, see [my talk at last year's London Perl Workshop](http://www.presentingperl.org/lpw2010/perl-and-unicode-in-search-of-the-holy-grail/) for a more detailed look at Perl and Unicode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, $CGI::PARAM_UTF8=1 doesn't solve my issue. I also tried setting AddDefaultCharset utf-8 via htaccess since I don't have full access to the servers config files, but no success. I still need decode() on the server while my Ubuntu doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The solution here is the ordering.

```
$dbh->{mysql_enable_utf8} = 1;
$dbh->connect ...
$dbh->do('SET NAMES \'utf8\';') || die;
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

In the past I needed to make sure my DBI behaved properly with utf8 by doing:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(...);
$dbh->{mysql_enable_utf8} = 1;
$dbh->do("set names 'utf8';");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all my condolances about your latin->utf8 job. I did that for a large application a few years back and the wrinkles it got me still haven't worn off.

What I recommend you to do is turn everything into UTF8 and not try to do decoding and stuff. That will definitely screw up somewhere. storing utf8 data in a latin table is a recipe for disaster. I remember at one point having double and tripple encoded utf8 strings in my database and no way to tell how to get back the original string.

The steps you should take:

1. Create a secondary database structure with UTF8 collated table instead of latin
2. extract everything out of your primary database and insert into the new database (hoping you haven't stored any utf8 strings in there yet)
3. make sure the Mime headers your application sends the browser specifies the encoding is in utf8, all data you get back from these pages automatically take the encoding of the page itself
4. cross your fingers and take a vacation...

You shouldn't have to change much in your application since the DBI utf8 handling is fairly good at this time.

Good luck!

Rob

Comment: -1 for the advice to "not try to do decoding and stuff". This contradicts the sense laid out in the documentation at http://p3rl.org/UNI

Comment: ditto - given Perl's handling of unicode that's a recipe for Mojibake.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I am lucky enough to work with an empty database so everything is utf8.

Comment: Well thanks guys for bashing someone for actually trying to help another. I just wanted to warn Thomas not to use encoding and decoding in his production system and still storing everything an a latin1 encoded database... I used to encode and decode every single string in my system manually, until it almost drove me nuts

Comment: Rob, thanks, your answer was actually really helpful. Now I now I am not the only one with a working utf-8 framework that doesn't use de/encode() :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://sax-appeal.blogspot.com/2009/12/unicode-and-encoding-problem.html). It is fairly general but it will get your lexicon straight and though many examples are in python, per is also there. BTW, if you try to stuff latin-1 (or other) encoded stuff without decoding/reencoding, disaster will ensue.

For more help, post specifics.

Cheers